# Getting a weird output using \alignat (picture and code included)

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

When I run the following code

```
 \begin{alignat}{2}
 \text{min} & \sum_{t\in T}\sum_{v\in V}\sum_{(i,j)\in W_{v}}(c_{ijv}-u_{i}-           v{j})x_{ijvt}+\sum_{j\in J}\sum_{t\in T}M_{jt}s_{jt} \\
 \text{s.t. } & l_{i,t-1}+s_{it}^{+}-\sum_{v\in V}\sum_{(i,j)\in W_{v}} x_{ijvt}=l_{it}, \forall i\in I, t\in T.\\
\text{} & \sum_{v\in V}\sum_{p\in T,p\leqq t}\sum_{(i,j)\in W_{v}}x_{ijvp}+s_{jt}\geqq d_{jt}^{+}, \forall j\in J, t\in T\\
\text{} & \sum_{v\in V}\sum_{p\in T,p\leqq t}\sum_{(i,j)\in W_{v}} x_{ijvp}\leqq d_{jt}^{+}, \forall j\in J,t\in T\\
\text{} \sum_{t\in T}\sum_{v\in V}\sum_{(i,j)\in W_{v}} p_{ij}x_{ijvt} = h^{+} \\
\text{} \sum_{(i,j)\in W_{v}} p_{ij}x_{ijvt}\leqq h_{vt}h^{+}, \forall v\in V, t\in T \\
\text{} & x_{ijvt} \geqq 0, \forall v\in V, (i,j)\in W_{v}, t\in T \\
\text{} & l_{it}\geqq 0, \forall i\in I, t\in T \\
\text{} & s_{jk} \geqq 0, \forall j\in J,t\in T 
\end{alignat}
```

I get the output as in the file I've attached. I have no idea how to fix this, when trying to search the web I've found that you could change the number in \begin{alignat}{number} but I've gotten the same output every time.

I hope someone can give me some help

I use MikTeX and the required packages for alignat.

EDIT: I saw the output now and it appears to have created another problem. Using the code provided by ergreg I get the output in the picture. The names of the equations are not aligned with the equations themselves because of too long equations. Is there a clever way to overcome this problem?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `alignat`, actually. Also, since you're typesetting in a two column format, you want to reduce the horizontal size, which can be obtained by merging the double and triple summations:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
\min & 
  \sum_{\substack{t\in T\\v\in V\\(i,j)\in W_{v}}}(c_{ijv}-u_{i}-v{j})x_{ijvt}+
  \sum_{\substack{j\in J\\t\in T}}M_{jt}s_{jt} \\
\text{s.t. } &
  l_{i,t-1}+s_{it}^{+}-
  \mspace{-6mu}\sum_{\substack{v\in V\\(i,j)\in W_{v}}}\mspace{-6mu} x_{ijvt}=l_{it},
  \forall i\in I, t\in T.\\
& \sum_{\substack{v\in V\\p\in T,\,p\leqq t\\(i,j)\in W_{v}}} x_{ijvp}+s_{jt}\geqq d_{jt}^{+},
  \forall j\in J, t\in T\\
& \sum_{\substack{v\in V\\p\in T,\,p\leqq t\\(i,j)\in W_{v}}} x_{ijvp}\leqq d_{jt}^{+},
  \forall j\in J,t\in T\\
& \sum_{\substack{t\in T\\v\in V\\(i,j)\in W_{v}}} p_{ij}x_{ijvt} = h^{+} \\
& \sum_{(i,j)\in W_{v}} p_{ij}x_{ijvt}\leqq h_{vt}h^{+}, \forall v\in V, t\in T \\
& x_{ijvt} \geqq 0, \forall v\in V, (i,j)\in W_{v}, t\in T \\
& l_{it}\geqq 0, \forall i\in I, t\in T \\
& s_{jk} \geqq 0, \forall j\in J,t\in T 
\end{align}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Don't forget to have an `&` in each line; `\text{min}` is wrong, because it should simply be `\min`. Note a couple of refinements:

1. in the second line I have added some backing up before and after the summation which has a wide subscript;
2. where two conditions are in the same substack line, I have added `\,` for giving some room.

[image]

Comment: That is very beautiful! When I tried to use it at home it became quite messy though, which I believe is because of the font sizes and font in particular. The font specification in lipsum, is it the same as in general research articles? Do you happen to know which size and font it is if so?

Comment: @GustavDanell `lipsum` just provides mock text, it does nothing to fonts.

Answer (score 7):

lines 5 and 6 have no `&` after `\text{}`, so everything in those lines will be
aligned to the left of the alignment point.  that will have the effect of
shifting all the other lines to the right.

(really, a minimum example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`,
and showing what packages you are using, would be more helpful.  it needn't include
anything more than the problematic display environment in the body.  it should just be
enough to make it possible for others to compile it and look at the output and log.)

Comment: Thanks alot! Did not see the missing &'s. I was focusing on finding  if there were some other syntax error which was undetected by the compiler so I completely did not see those. Adding the amprasams fixed the problem. Very helpful to know to include those lines. Thanks for that too!